# How does the computer turns physically different bits on and off?

Tags: architecture

How does the computer turns physically different bits on and off?
I mean that the electricity flows to the transistors in order to turn them on or off but there are many transistors so what part in the hardware makes some of them on while the others off. There are no different wire for each transistor so what is it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read up on [Electronic Circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_circuit), [Transistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor), and [Integrated Circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit).